# python numpy stack matrices and add specific corner/column entries

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Say we have two matrices A and B with a size of 2 by 2. Is there a command that can stack them horizontally and add A[:,1] to B[:,0] so that the resulting matrix C is 2 by 3, with `C[:,0] = A[:,0], C[:,1] = A[:,1] + B[:,0], C[:,2] = B[:,1]`. One step further, stacking them on diagonal so that `C[0:2,0:2] = A, C[1:2,1:2] = B, C[1,1] = A[1,1] + B[0,0]`. C is 3 by 3 in this case. Hard coding this routine is not hard, but I'm just curious since MATLAB has a similar function if my memory serves me well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward approach is to copy or add the two arrays to a target:

```
In [882]: A=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [883]: C=np.zeros((2,3),int)
In [884]: C[:,:-1]=A
In [885]: C[:,1:]+=A   # or B
In [886]: C
Out[886]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [2, 5, 3]])
```

Another approach is to to pad `A` at the end, pad `B` at the start, and sum; while there is a convenient `pad` function, it won't be any faster.

And for the diagonal

```
In [887]: C=np.zeros((3,3),int)
In [888]: C[:-1,:-1]=A
In [889]: C[1:,1:]+=A
In [890]: C
Out[890]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

Again the 2 arrays could be `pad` and added.

I'm not aware of any specialized function to do this; even if there were, it probably would do the same thing.  This isn't a common enough operation to justify a compiled version.

I have built up finite element sparse matrices by adding over lapping element matrices.  The sparse formats for both MATLAB and scipy facilitate this (duplicate coordinates are summed).

============

```
In [896]: np.pad(A,[[0,0],[0,1]],mode='constant')+np.pad(A,[[0,0],[1,0]],mode='
     ...: constant')
Out[896]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [2, 5, 3]])
In [897]: np.pad(A,[[0,1],[0,1]],mode='constant')+np.pad(A,[[1,0],[1,0]],mode='
     ...: constant')
Out[897]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

What's the special MATLAB code for doing this?

in Octave I found:

```
prepad(A,3,0,axis=2)+postpad(A,3,0,axis=2)
```